# Linear Transport Equation - Non-constant Speed

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

I'm struggling with the following question. I'm fairly new to PDEs as this is a question from an introductory course.

$$u_t + (x^2u)_x=0$$
$$u(x,0)=1$$

I know it's of the form *linear transport equation with non-constant speed*:

$$u_t+(v(x)u)_x=0$$
$$u(x,0)=u_0(x)$$

and thus I know the characteristic line $x(t)$ satisfies

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x)=x^2$$
$$x(0)=x_0$$

and that the solution to the IVP is

$$u(x(t;x_0),t)=u_0(x_0)\frac{v(x_0)}{v(x(t;x_0))}$$

However, I'm not sure how to find $x_0$, and then use this in the answer formula.

**EDIT - REPHRASING THE QUESTION**

The text I'm using (and the above is based on) is Li Chen's lecture notes "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations" it states:

> The Cauchy problem we consider in this part is \begin{equation}u_t+(v(x)u)_x=0, \text{   in } \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_+\end{equation}
>   $$u(x,0)=u_0(x)$$
>   where $v(x)$ is a given Lipschitz continous function.
>   A reformulation of the equation is $$u_t+v(x)u_x+v'(x)u=0.$$
>   If $v(x)$ is Lipschitz cont., then the characteristic line $x(t)$ satisfies
>   $$\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x)=x^2$$
>   $$x(0)=x_0$$
>   With the help of this line, the equation is rewritten into
>   $$\frac{du(x(t;x_0),t)}{dt}=-v'(x(t;x_0))u,$$
>   $$u(x(t;x_0),t)|_{t=0}=u_0(x_0).$$
>   By separation of variables in solving ODE, we have 
>   \begin{align*}\ln u(x(t;x_0),t)&=\ln u_0(x_0)+\int_0^t-v'(x(\tau;x_0))d\tau\\
> &=\ln u_0(x_0)+\int^{x(t;x_0)}_{x_0}-\frac{v'(x)}{v(x)}dx\\
> &=\ln u_0(x_0)-\ln v(x(t;x_0))+\ln v(x_0)\end{align*}
>   where in the first equation the change of variable $x=x(\tau,x_0)$, $dx=x'd\tau=v(x)d\tau$ is used. 
>   So the problem has solution $$u(x(t;x_0),t)=u_0(x_0)\frac{v(x_0)}{v(x(t;x_0))}.$$
>   Therefore, finding the exact solution of the homogenous problem is reduced to the solvability of the characteristic line.

So in trying to solve my problem in this manner, I'm kinda confused with how I go from the PDE to the characteristic line (and $x(0)=x_0$), and how to interpret the $x_0$ value, since it is not given in my problem.
Can anybody help me and walk me through it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the pde 
$$
u_t+x^2u_x+2xu=0\\
u(x,0)=1
$$
which we examine along a characteristic curve $(t,x(t))$ which we require to satisfy the convenient conditions
$$
x'(t)=x^2\\
\frac{d}{dt}u(t,x(t))=u_t+x'(t)u_x=-2x(t)u(t,x(t))
$$
So let's solve the odes. First we find
$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0}-t}
$$
then 
$$
u'(t,x(t))=-2x(t)u(t)=\frac{2}{t-\frac{1}{x_0}}u(t)\\
\implies u(t)=A(t-1/x_0)^2
$$
Now we impose that $u(0)=1$ to find $A=x_0^2$, yielding
$$
u(t,x(t))=x_0^2(t-1/x_0)^2
$$
at which point we need to solve for $x_0$, which after all was just a dummy initial condition. We want our solution to  be valid for any initial condition $x_0$. So we solve for $x_0$ in terms of $x$ to find
$$
x_0=\frac{tx+1}{x}
$$
which then yields the solution
$$
u(t,x)=\frac{x^2}{(tx+1)^2}\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{(tx+1)^2}
$$

edit: How $x'(t)=x^2$ is solved. Separate variables to find
$$
\frac{dx}{x^2}=\mathrm dt\implies -\frac{1}{x}=t+c
$$
for some $c$ which we will solve for in terms of initial condition $x(0)=x_0$, plug in $t=0$ and find
$$
-\frac{1}{x_0}=c
$$
yielding 
$$
-\frac{1}{x}=t-\frac{1}{x_0}\implies x=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0}-t}
$$
as we found before.

edit 2 explicitly solving other ode:
$$
\frac{du}{u}=2(t-1/x_0)^{-1}\stackrel{\text{integrate both sides}}{\implies} \ln|u|=2\ln(t-1/x_0)+C=\ln(t-1/x_0)^2+C\\
\stackrel{\text{exponentiate both sides}}{\implies}u(x,t)=A(t-1/x_0)^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=f(t)g(x)$ then $u_t=f^{'}(t)g(x)$ and $(x^2u)_x=f(t)(2xg(x)+x^2g^{'}(x))$ and we have:

$\Large f^{'}(t)g(x)+f(t)(2xg(x)+x^2g^{'}(x))=0$

Dividing it by $u$:

$\Large {f^{'}(t)\over{f(t)}}+{{2xg(x)+x^2g^{'}(x)}\over g(x)}=0$

therefore there must be:

$\Large {f^{'}(t)\over{f(t)}}=k$ and $\Large{{2xg(x)+x^2g^{'}(x)}\over g(x)}=-k$

where $k$ is constant. The above two equations yield:

$\Large f(t)=Ae^{kt}\qquad\qquad\qquad g(x)={B{e^{k\over x}}\over{x^2}}$

finally we have:

$\Large u(x,t)=A{e^{kt+{k\over x}}\over{x^2}}$.

Since $A$ can vary with $k$ we write the general form using Fourier transform:

$\Large u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A(\omega){e^{(t+{1\over x})\omega}\over {x^2}}d\omega$

After imposing the condition of problem we have the final answer:

$\Huge u(x,t)={1\over{(xt+1)^2}}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you show it in terms of characteristics, since I was supposed to do it in this fashion? Thank you.

Comment: Don't mention it!....which characteristics and fashion you exactly mean?

Comment: I have just made an edit in the question where I have cited the text I'm using. I have mentioned the part I'm confused about.

Comment: I have never seen this method (not separation of variables but the fourier transform business) but like it. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I would also like a reference on it. And can you maybe elaborate the step where you use the Fourier transform?

Comment: Sure!....My main reference is "Advanced Engineering Mathematics" written by Erwin Keryszig and is really useful specially for undergraduate courses.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate the step where you use the Fourier transform? Maybe in an edit with another calculation. The transform is (to my knowledge): 1/sqrt(2 pi) * int_R f(x) e^{-ikx} dx

Comment: since all of functions we found according to constants and variables $x,t$ can be responses to the PDE so can be any linear combination of  them with different coefficients. In fact the Fourier transform indicated on such thing so and is the same different coefficients that should be mentioned generally by integral since it is continuous.

Comment: @qbert: The name Fourier transform is a red herring, the fact that it can indeed be convert into one on the complex plane notwithstanding. It is simply the expression for linear superposition of solutions, which in this particular case come from separation of variables, for a linear PDE.

Comment: Well!.....this is also linear since $u_t-2xu-x^2u_x=0$

Comment: @Hans this makes perfect sense thank you

Comment: Constant coefficients is a special case of linear for example $y^{'}=xy$ is linear but not with constant coefficients.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz thank you for the reference, which I just saw. Indeed, I think the linearity is what allows you to do this and to which Hans is referring

Comment: Don't mention it!!!!

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: Is your comment on the current PDE being also linear directed at me? Yes, it is linear. That was what I said. Do you mean the fact is contradicting what I said?

Comment: @qbert: You are welcome.